# C++ executes blanks after class creation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ to help my sibling with their assignment. So I'm attempting the assignment. It's a simple program to load a dictionary test file with words, their type, and definition to an array of *Word* type objects. I was able to get started with a normal string array instead of an object array as requested. But as soon as I defined the *Word* class and the array the code builds without an issue. When I try to run the code the cursor simply blinks for a few seconds and returns to the normal terminal.
Am I doing something wrong with my Class constructor ??

````
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Word {
        public: 
            string WordEntry;
            string Type;
            string Definition;
        //constructor
        Word(string word, string type, string definition){
            WordEntry=word;
            Type=type;
            Definition=definition;
        }
    };

    int main(){
        cout << "Test1";
        Word *wordArray[318555];
        int count=0;
        string  word, type, definition,blank;
        cout << "TEST" << count << "\n";
        ifstream file("dictionary2021 (1).txt");
        if (file.is_open()){
            cout << "File dictionary2021.txt has been opened \n";
            while (!file.eof()){
                getline(file,word);
                getline(file,type);
                getline(file,definition);
                getline(file,blank);
                wordArray[count]= new Word(word,type,definition);
                count++;
            }
            file.close();
            cout << "File dictionary2021.txt has " << count/3 << " entries\n";
        }
        cout << "TEST" << count << endl;
        cout << cc; 
        int selection;
        string input; 
        cout << "Function List - Please hit Enter after your selection \n";
        cout << " 1. Word Search \n 2. Repetitive z search \n 3. Wild Card Search\n";
        cout << "Selection:";
        cin >> selection;
        if(selection=1){
            cout << "Enter word:\n";
            cin >> input;
            string str("a");
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i+3)
            {
                cout << "1";
                if (input.compare(str)== 0)
                {
                    cout << wordArray[i+1];
                    return 0;
                }
                cout << "2";
            }
            
        }
    }```
````

Comment: `Word *wordArray[318555];` could be too large to fit on the stack. You could temporarily move the declaration before the `main` function to make it global to see if that helps. In general global variables are best avoided so if that works you might consider other options like a `std::vector<Word>` or dynamic allocation with `new`.

Comment: BTW: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, you should have extracted a [mcve] from your code, which might have brought you to the same conclusion, i.e. that the size of the local array is too large.

Answer (score 0):

`Word* wordArray[318555];` is a huge value and we're talking about 2548440 bytes (or roughly 2.4MB). This might be too large for a single stack frame and can easily be inefficient.

What I suggest is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store the word array and use `std::vector<>::push_back()` method to insert data to it.

Note: In your code snippet your not deallocating the `Word` object pointers once everything is done. Either explicitly delete those pointers using `delete` or use a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).